# How to speed up GTK 3 WebKit2 view slowed down by cache?

Tags: caching, webkit, gtk, gtk3

I have a simple GTK3 app with a single full screen WebKitWebView (WebKit version 2). I'm loading a static page and some assets from `http://localhost`. The first time I run my app, it takes 9 seconds to load (from COMMITTED to FINISHED). It takes 0.5 seconds each time after.

I've noticed that this is all related to some cache files in `~/.cache`. If I remove that directory, I get the 9 seconds load time. I know that it doesn't take 9 seconds for my local server to serve the files, because I have timing inside the server indicating times of less than 1 ms for each asset. How do I speed up this webview's load time?

For reference:

```
$ du -csh .cache/webkitgtk/ .cache/gtk_kiosk/
4.0K    .cache/webkitgtk/
544K    .cache/gtk_kiosk/
548K    total

$ du -sh /www/
1.3M    /www/
```

I thought that I would try disabling the cache to see what happens, but nothing I've tried works. The cache is always there after I run the app.

**UPDATE**: I figured out how to disable the cache, but it is still slow the first time. I no longer get the cache files, but I still get the timing above. Strangely, now that I've disabled the cache, I don't have a way of reproducing the 9 second load time without rebooting.

WebKit2Gtk API Reference: https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/

the actual code:

```cs
WebKitWebsiteDataManager *manager =
  webkit_website_data_manager_new("base-cache-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "base-data-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "disk-cache-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "indexeddb-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "local-storage-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "offline-application-cache-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  "websql-directory", "/dev/null",
                                  NULL);
WebKitWebContext *context = webkit_web_context_new_with_website_data_manager(manager);
webkit_web_context_set_cache_model (context, WEBKIT_CACHE_MODEL_DOCUMENT_VIEWER);

GtkWidget *webView = webkit_web_view_new_with_context(context);

WebKitSettings *settings = webkit_web_view_get_settings(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webView));
webkit_settings_set_enable_page_cache(settings, FALSE);
webkit_settings_set_enable_offline_web_application_cache(settings, FALSE);
webkit_web_view_set_settings(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webView), settings);

webkit_web_view_load_uri(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webView), url);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the [Accelerated compositing in WebKitGTK+](https://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2017/02/10/).

Try setting an environment variable `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1` to see anything changes.

[This mailing list thread](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-gtk/2016-September/002803.html) might also help.